# thanos - how to remove stores that are in DOWN status

Tags: prometheus

is there way to remove stale stores from thanos? they are in DOWN status since last 26 hours, does thanos auto-clean that or is there way to remove those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restarting querier service resets the targets, in my case i deleted that pod and could see that the stale targets are cleared

```
kubectl -n monitoring delete po thanos-query-7b49d758c-6m2tg
```